# SLDs imported from ArcMap do not apply on Geoserver

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, sld

I've exported shapefiles and SLDs from ArcGIS to deploy them on GeoServer. The client was using field names longer than 10 symbols so they got truncated. The field upon which the symbology is mainly built turned from `SubTypeCode` to `SUBTYPECOD`. I fixed the `.sld`s, so my rules became:

```
    <Rule>
      <Name><![CDATA[Cable Duct]]></Name>
      <Title><![CDATA[Cable Duct]]></Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>941</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke" >#00ab1a</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

On the other hand, my data view says:

[image]

But it simply does not apply, I can clearly see that it's falling back to the default symbolizer that is in the end of the `.sld`. Has anyone ever had something like this?

```
<NamedLayer>
    <Name><![CDATA[HAL_OilGas_Line]]></Name>
    <UserStyle>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Cable Duct]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Cable Duct]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>941</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#00ab1a</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Cable Tray]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Cable Tray]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>935</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#960062</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Mapping Limit Extent]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Mapping Limit Extent]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>920</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#9e6c00</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Pipe Bridge Line]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Pipe Bridge Line]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>926</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#0049b0</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Pipeline]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Pipeline]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>909</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#00528c</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[Piping]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[Piping]]></Title>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>SUBTYPECOD</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>1049</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#003780</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name><![CDATA[<all other values>]]></Name>
                <Title><![CDATA[<all other values>]]></Title>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke" >#3ca300</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width" >1</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity" >1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
```

Comment: After importing the sld, did you actually publish the layer with this particular sld?

Comment: of course I did) I see it falling through all the rules to the default one. But all the features actually have this property

Comment: In that case, the error is somewhere else in the SLD. Can you share the whole SLD?

Comment: Added the whole body of SLD

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I was ignorant to the fact that they're cascading so I completely trusted those auto-generated `.sld`s. The most general rule had to come first.

Thanks everybody.

By the way, if someone is interested how I extracted the SLDs - I did it with the trial version of Arc2Earth. It only allows you to do that layer by layer, but at least it's possible.

Comment: Aha yes, That's an Important point that I tend to forget quite often.